Next.js SEO meta tags in <Head> element not received with the first page request in a deployed app. They do not exist in the Page Source
I am using Pages Router with Next version 14.2.3.
I have set up various dynamic meta tags + the  using the Head component from next/head in a page level component that also utilizes getServerSideProps. The data is fetched dynamically (server side) and passed as a prop to the component.
The component then uses the  component to set the meta tags accordingly:


<Head>
    <title key="title">{`${title}`}</title>
    <meta key="metatitle" name="title" content={metaTitle ?? title} />
    <meta key="og:title" name="description" content={description} />
    {author && <meta name="author" content={author} />}
    <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
    <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
    {socialImageUrl && <meta key="og:image" property="og:image" content={socialImageUrl} />}
    {videoUrl && <meta property="og:video" content={videoUrl} />}
    <meta key="twitter:card" name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
    {socialImageUrl && <meta key="twitter:image" name="twitter:image" content={socialImageUrl} />}
    {socialImageUrl && <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content={imageAltTag ?? title} />}
</Head>



The result in localhost is correct. After running npm run build and npm run start, the very first request made has the  elements correctly set in the document's .
When I make the same request to the deployed app's URL, then the  data is send via a chunk "_app-followinghash" and NOT with the first initial page HTML GET request.
This is absolutely frustrating and I have searched far-and-wide + debugged this problem as best as I can.
Only pages that have meta tags on the initial request are static pages that do not fetch data via getServerSideProps.
I do not have any if statements blocking the return of the  element as well.
Does anyone else have a clue what might be wrong?
I have tried setting the most basic  titles in my _app.tsx via the  component imported from next/head.
I have tried logging the rendered pages' content from _document.tsx and seen that the SEO meta data is indeed not there when the app is deployed and running in production mode.
Keep in mind that when I run the app in production mode locally, the meta data is correctly passed to the inital request's response and NOT passed via a bundle of JS (which is the 2nd or 3rd request made after the first page GET)
